# Ligação de Tabelas - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, tabela-banco-de-dados, inner-join

Estou montando um sistema para o usuário cadastrar/deletar/editar/visualizar cursos da escola onde trabalho, montei todas as tabelas certinhos porém quando vou fazer um `inner join` em uma das tabelas não me dá o resultado esperado que eu gostaria.

Eu possuo as seguintes tabelas:

- `curso` (`idCurso, curso_nome, curso_descricao, curso_imagem, curso_carga, Preco_idPreco`)
- `curso_categoria` (`idCurso_Categoria, Categoria_Curso_idCategoria_Curso, Curso_idCurso`)
- `categoria_curso` (`idCategoria_Curso, categoria_curso_nome, categoria_curso_descricao, categoria_curso_image`)
- `materia` (`idMateria, materia_nome, materia_conteudo`)
- `curso_materia` (`idCurso_Materia, Curso_idCurso, Materia_idMateria`)
- `preco` (`idPreco, preco_valor`)

Essas são as tabelas do meu sistema, o meu problema está quando eu faço um `inner join` e tento buscar as informações da tabela associativa `curso_materia`.

#### Meu código

```
select curso.idCurso, curso.curso_nome, curso.curso_carga, 
preco.preco_valor,
categoria_curso.categoria_curso_nome from curso

inner join preco on preco.idPreco = curso.Preco_idPreco
inner join curso_categoria on curso_categoria.Curso_idCurso = curso.idCurso
inner join categoria_curso on categoria_curso.idCategoria_Curso = curso_categoria.Categoria_Curso_idCategoria_Curso


/*
inner join curso_materia on curso_materia.idCurso_Materia = curso.idCurso
inner join materia on materia.idMateria = curso_materia.Materia_idMateria
*/
```

Ok! O resultado esperado quando não adiciono a linha que está no comentário está certinho e o resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora se eu adiciono no meu código aquela linha do comentário, que ficaria assim:

#### Código com o comentário anterior

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E me aparece isso.

Ok, vamos a algumas observações que talvez eu não tenha citado anteriormente...

- Estou usando o Mysql
- Foi adicionado apenas 2 matérias para os testes (Conceitos Avançados e Análise de Cores)
- A **imagem 2** queria que retornasse 2 vezes a parte de Colorimetria, porém com matérias diferentes, igual a imagem a seguir:
  (edição feita no Paint)

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Tabela Curso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Tabela Associativa: `Curso_Materia`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Tabela Matéria

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde estou errando? Aparentemente a tabela curso, curso_categoria e categoria_curso deram certos, e são N:N...

PS: O meu foco mesmo é a parte do relacionamento entre essas tabelas, a tabela usuário em sí aqui eu não coloquei por conta de que só iria dar mais trabalho aos leitores (ou ajudaria...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema está no primeiro join comentado, onde você está fazendo o join de `curso_materia.idCurso_Materia` com `curso.idCurso`. Se essa tabela é de uma associação N:N, ela deveria fazer join de `curso_materia.Curso_idCurso` com `curso.idCurso`. Dessa forma:

```
inner join curso_materia on curso_materia.Curso_idCurso = curso.idCurso
```

Comment: Valeu, eu não estava sabendo ao certo, pq eu usando muito inner join e acabei me perdendo... É normal? E sobre os joins, é assim mesmo que se usam? Ou tem uma solução mais fácil de resolver isso...?

Comment: Normal é sim, principalmente quando o banco tem muitas tabelas e existem diversas maneiras de se usar joins. Provavelmente existem soluções que otimizam as buscas, possam apresentar uma simplicidade maior mas meu conhecimento é bem curto e ainda não sei muito.